# How to create an array out of certain values in hashes, which are contained in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of hashes:

```
a = [{name: "ben", sex: "m"},{name: "sarah", sex: "f"}]
```

What is the easiest way to create an array out of this with just the names? So I end up with:

```
b = ["ben", "sarah"]
```

I know you can do the following, but just wondering if there's a shortcut

```
b = []
a.each do |x|
    b << x[:name]
end
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = a.map { |hash| hash[:name] }
```

This is pretty basic Ruby, take a look at the [Enumerable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) and study all the methods carefully. [edit] Some random links about the topic: [1](http://railspikes.com/2008/7/29/functional-loops-in-ruby-each-map-inject-select-and-for), [2](http://railspikes.com/2008/8/11/understanding-map-and-reduce), [3](http://billsix.blogspot.com/2008/03/functional-collection-patterns-in-ruby.html).